Use of GROUP BY with ORDER BY in MYSQL
My written query is:-
Query 1:
SELECT CONCAT( "There are a total of " ," ", COUNT(OCCUPATION) ," ", LOWER(OCCUPATION) , "s." ) AS ENT
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
GROUP BY OCCUPATION 
ORDER BY COUNT(OCCUPATION),NAME;

ERROR I am getting is :

ERROR 1055 (42000) at line 5: Expression #2 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'OCCUPATIONS.Name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Query 2(This is getting accpted):
SELECT CONCAT( "There are a total of " ," ", COUNT(OCCUPATION) ," ", LOWER(OCCUPATION) , "s." ) AS ENT
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
GROUP BY OCCUPATION 
ORDER BY ENT;

Can someone please explain the Error and mistake I am making in the first query.
NOTE: This is "The PADS" question under Advanced Select in HackerRank.
I was expecting to sort the query first by count of occupation and then by occupation alphabetically but I am getting a error while doing that. I want to understand the mistake which I am doing.

You use ORDER BY .. , NAME - but NAME is not either a part of grouping expression or an argument of aggreagte function.

You are grouping by OCCUPATION, so by the time it gets to ORDER BY there is one result row to sort for each OCCUPATION.  As far as mysql can tell, there could be multiple NAME values grouped together and so you cannot refer to a single NAME.  Historically mysql has allowed this and just picked an arbitrary one of the NAME values to use, but for a long time now the only_full_group_by mode has been a default, giving you an error when you do this.
If in fact there is only one NAME per OCCUPATION, you can simply change your GROUP BY to OCCUPATION, NAME.  Or if you don't care which NAME value is used, you can do ORDER BY COUNT(OCCUPATION), MAX(NAME) (or MIN, or ANY_VALUE).
Ah, reading the HackerRank question it is clear you meant to be doing ORDER BY COUNT(OCCUPATION), OCCUPATION, not NAME at all; NAME is a person's name, and you can expect there to be multiple NAMEs with the same OCCUPATION.
